# SQL Aggregate Subtotal

Tags: sql, aggregate

```
DATE|Sales
1|2
1|3
2|2
2|4
2|2
3|3
4|4
4|5
5|3
5|3
6|3
7|2
7|2
```

I have a table which is in this format. The first column is the date and the second one is the sales in dollars.
The table is 2 million rows.

So from the above table we can get that

- after the first day we gained 5$
- after the second day we gained 13$
- after the third day we gained 16$
- after the fourth day we gained 25$
- after the fifth day we gained 31$
- after the sixth day we gained 34$
- after the seventh day we gained 38 $

What i want is to create a function to calculate the sales from one specific day (this date would be the input parameter  to the function) to the most recent date to the table.

For example i would like to calculate the sales after the 5th 6th and 7th of the month.
Imagine that my table is two million rows and the dates instead of 3  (like in the previous case e.g.5th 6th and 7th) they  might me thousands. Which is the most efficient way of doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sounds like you're basically going to be doing a table scan no matter what, it's just you need to start part-way down. I'm guessing the timestamp is indexed? Try doing WHERE date > START_DATE, and then you just do a sum(sales) as usual. Not sure that there's a more efficient way.

Comment: is was thinking if is possible to do the scan just once to get the basis. where the basis will be the sum(sales for the start date) and after that start adding the sales of the next days

Comment: that would be incredibly inefficient. you need to think in terms of sets, not procedures. a simple sum() where date > yourdate is going to be the most efficient manner